# Rebinding events in Foundation 6 after add elements to the DOM via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a rails app with Zurb Foundation 6.3, and I have an infinite scrolling feature on the home page, every element has a link to a reveal modal, the first shown elements's reveal modal work ok, however when I click on one of the elements loaded via AJAX through the infinite scrolling feature don't show up the reveal modal, it just doesn't work.

I know I need to rebind the events in the elements loaded via AJAX, I used to do it in Foundation 5 through:

```
$(document).foundation({bindings: 'events'});
```

However it doesn't work with Foundation 6...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only works with Foundation items, if you are trying to rebind something that does not use Zurb Foundation this will not be the solution to the problem

**Solution:** Just add this to the end of your AJAX call

$(document).foundation();

Answer (score 2):

No code shown here to work on, but I reckon you will get the general idea.

While you are scrolling, items get appended to some parent element. You need to locate a parent to all the fetched items that is always there.

For the sake of the example, the parent will be `#container` (or `document` if there is no other common parent element)  and the fetched rows will have a  clickable `.item` that will fire you ajax.

Your event listener should be of the following format:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.item', function() {
    //whatever it is you do
});
```

This way, you bind to `#container`, which is always there, not the `.item`'s.

Nothing more needs to be done, no rebindings or stuff